# Is Python 3.3 better than 2.7 for Decoding and Re-Encoding Scraped Web Text to UTF-8?? Like, a lot better?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

There are seemingly a million questions involving Python Unicode Errors where the `...ordinal [is] not in range(128)`.  Seemingly, the vast majority involve Python 2.x.

I know about these errors because I am currently in encoding, decoding hell.  For a side-project, I scrape web pages and attempt to normalize that text data, so that it doesn't appear on our site with crazy characters.  To normalize the data, I rely on HTMLParser's `HTMLParser()` and `entitydefs`, as well as decoding the text from whatever its original form  was (`string.decode('[original encoding]', 'ignore'))` and encoding it as UTF-8 (`string.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')`).

Yet, seemingly, there's always a site on which my best efforts fail, raising the same old `UnicodeError: ASCII decoding error...ordinal not in range(128).`  It's so annoying.

I've read ([here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html) and [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html)) that in Python 3 all text is Unicode.  While I've read a lot about Unicode, because I'm not a software engineer, I don't know whether Unicode is objectively better (i.e., lower failure rate) than 2.x's default ascii encoding option.  I have to think anything would be better, but I'd like if someone more expert and experienced could lend some perspective.

I'd like to know whether I should migrate to Python 3 for its (improved) processing of text scraped from the web.  I am hoping that someone here can explain (or suggest resources that explain) the pros and cons of Python 3's approach to text processing.  Is it better??  Is there someone who's dealt with my same problem who's already migrated to Python 3??  Would he/she recommend that I start using Python 3, if the `2to3` migration weren't an issue??

Thank you in advance for any assistance.  I sure need it.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: Do read the link @dan04 gave.  Python 3 is far better than Python 2 here *once you know what you're doing* because of "explicit is better than implicit".  That is, Python 3 builds a tall wall between Unicode strings and byte sequences - many problems here in Python 2 are due to misguided attempts to "magically" convert between them.

Comment: @dan04 I'll definitely read it.  Thank you, guys.

Comment: On hold as opinion-based?  That's insane - everyone answering this had the *same* opinion: Python 3 is better here than Python 2.  And why should that be surprising?  Guido van Rossum very deliberately changed Python 3 to make working with Unicode better than it was in Python 2.  And reading the links supplied here spell out *why* that's so in detail.  This isn't opinion at all:  it's the  intended result of deliberate design changes based on over a decade of experience with Unicode problems in Python 2. Perhaps the people who voted this are the ones with baseless opinions? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll speak from the point of view of a Python 2.7 user.

It's true that Python 3 introduces some big changes on the `Unicode` field. I won't say it is easier to work with `encodings` in Python 3, but it's indeed more reasonable for doing i18n stuff.

Like I said, I use Python 2.7 and so far I've been able to handle every `encoding` problem I've found. You just have to understand what's going on under the hood, and have a very reasonable background of what `encodings` is all about, of course: [this is the best article there is to understand encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

In that article, Joel says something that you need to keep in mind **every time you encounter yourself in an `encoding` situation**:

> It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.

Having said that, my suggestion to approach your problem with Python 2.7 would be something like this:

1. Read Joel's article of course (great reading and will take only 30 minutes or less)
2. Figure out what `encoding` the web page is using (you can sense this by looking at the `Response headers` or in a field in `BeautifulSoup`.
3. `.decode()` the retrieved string using the `encoding` you figured out
4. When you `decode`, you don't have a `str` object anymore, you have a `unicode` object.
5. `unicode` is just an internal representation, not a real encoding, so if you want to output the content somewhere, you'll have to `.encode()` it and I suggest you to use `utf-8` of course.

Now, some points have to be understood. Maybe the web page you're scraping is not *encoding aware* and it says it uses some `encoding` but doesn't stick to it. This is an error made by the webmaster, but you have to do something to figure it out. You have either 3 choices:

1. `,ignore` characters that can be problematic. Just quietly pass them.
2. There are good python libraries that try to figure out what encoding a string is using. Those are very accurate but of course, not a silver bullet. They can fail to guess, specially when the `encoding` is malformed
3. Get angry and drop the project ;) (I really don't recommend this one)

To get `encodings` right, some amount of discipline is needed from the source and from the client. You have to develop your program right, but you **need** that the information about encoding and the real encoding at the source match.

Python 3 improve its `unicode` handling but *if you don't understand what is going on, it will probably be useless*. The best thing you can do is understand `encodings` (ain't that hard, again, read Joel!) and once you understand it, you'll be able to process it with Python 2.7, Python 3.3 and even PHP ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations -- very helpful.

Comment: Very nice piece, full of good wholesome facts and none of those nasty opinion thingies!  ;)

Comment: @PauloBu Paulo, I attempted your recommendation, but I still _always_ get a failure.  Presently, it's these characters -- `ΓÇ£R` -- showing up. Do you have any idea what they are??

Comment: @PauloBu  ps: this is the complete line I receive after encoding the `unicode` object with `utf-8`:  `Andrew Dice Clay is proud to be America&#x27;s most controversial and outrageous comic of all
time. And itΓÇÖs that persona that has made Clay ΓÇ£The Undisputed ΓÇ£Heavy Weight King of Comedy.ΓÇ¥┬á`  Basically, there appears to be two types of encoding in one line...  Is there any hope or should I just choose option (3) from your above recommendations?? :)

Comment: Can you point me to where you're fetching this to see the exact bytes composing the string? Are you able to see the content well in the explorer? Point me to the source so maybe I can solve your problem and you get a better feeling of how working with encodings is like. I'll be glad to help!

Comment: @PauloBu here is the exact link from which I pulled the above line: http://www.zvents.com/scottsdale_az/events/show/338071883-scottsdale-arts-festival.  It's just one of many examples where it seems like the webmaster doesn't present a consistent `encoding`

Comment: @BeeSmears Don't worry I'll check them out and notify you later :)

Comment: @BeeSmears Are you sure this is the site? I mean, I can't find "Andrew Dice Clay" anywhere there. Ob the other side, the site is using utf-8. I was able to decode it an print it with no problem.

Comment: @PauloBu You're right.  I screwed it up and gave you the wrong url.  Sorry about that.  Yes, the charset is utf-8; and, taking your advice, I now check that for every page I'm interested in scraping -- no matter if it's the 100th page on a site.  Thank you.  Would you please check this address: http://www.zvents.com/glenside_pa/events/show/363193523-andrew-dice-clay.  Can you output the page's 'description' cleanly??  Thank you, Paulo.

Comment: @BeeSmears I was able to parse it correctly with this seq: `urllib2.urlopen`, `s=url.read()`, `u=s.decode('utf8')`. Now, once in unicode, converting it to latin1 is impossible because there is a unicode character (2019) (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) that can't be mapped. Anyways, with utf-8 you can do it. Any other problem?

Comment: @PauloBu Thank you, Paulo.  I don't know why it doesn't work for me, as I'm doing exactly the same thing as you (and experiencing the same annoying u/2019 issue).  It could be my parser then -- the thing I use to take `utf-8` encoding and return the appropriate symbol.  Presently I use `unescape()` method from `HTMLParser.HTMLParser()`.  Do you use something else??  I can't thank you enough for taking the time!!  You're the best!

Comment: @BeeSmears maybe HTMLParser is the one giving you errors. I didn't use it, just urllib2. Try with another parse, BeautifulSoup is really good and can handle encodings well.

Comment: @PauloBu Thank you, Paulo.  That must be it!