# Unsupported characters in input (Python 2.7.9)

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

A small question from a newbie. I am trying to do a little function where it randomizes the content of a text.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

def glitch(text):
    new_text = ['']
    for x in text:
        new_text.append(x)
        random.shuffle(new_text)
    return ''.join(new_text)
```

As you can see it is quite simple, and the output, when inputting a simple string, such as 'Hey how are you?' will result in a randomized sentence as predicted. However, when I try to paste something similar to this:

> print glitch('Iàäï�†n$§&0ñŒ≥Q¶µù`o¢y”—œº')

...Python 2.7.9 returns ***'Unsupported characters in input'*** -- I have looked around the forum and have tried things as far as I can understand, as I am still new to coding in general, but to no avail.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me in 2.7.5, whether printing from within the script or after importing to the console.

Comment: Is it possible that I am missing some preferences or maybe must download some packages in order to be able to use such input? I am on Mac OSX 10.10.1 -- I have tried multiple times to change in the preferences the three options (locale, utf-8, none) but nothing seems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

def glitch(text):

    new_text = ['']
    for x in text:
        new_text.append(x)
        random.shuffle(new_text)
    return ''.join(new_text)

print (glitch(u'Iàäï†n$§&0ñŒ≥Q¶µù`o¢y”—œº'))
```

This should work, through a quick google search of my own, I found out, you have to prepend the letter 'u', to mark the following text as unicode.

Source: [Unsupported characters in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873543/unsupported-characters-in-input)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the u infront doesn't do any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is Python 2.x -- not your specific version of Python 2.  Python 2.x uses `ascii` instead of Unicode encoding (changed in Python 3), and your string is (likley) encoded as `utf-8`.  See following:

```
import chardet
text = 'Iàäï†n$§&0ñŒ≥Q¶µù`o¢y”—œº'
print chardet.detect(text)['encoding'] # prints utf-8
```

If you download Python 3.X, your problem will likely be resolved, [since UTF-8 can handle any Unicode code point](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings).

If you're interested -- or for future 2.x users -- you can do the following.

```
def glitch(text):
    new_text = []
    for x in text:
        new_text.append(x)
    random.shuffle(new_text) #note you should just shuffle once - not every iteration.
    new_line = ''.join(new_text) # this line is where your encoding moves from `utf-8` to `ascii`
    # this becomes `ascii` because of the empty string you use to join your list.  it defaults to `ascii`
    # if you tried to make it `unicode` by doing `u''.join(list)` you would get a `UnicodeDecodeError`
    return new_line.decode("ascii", "ignore").encode("utf-8") # note the [ignore][2].  it bypasses encoding errors.
    # now your code will run and return a string of utf-8 characters 
    # (to which we encode new_line, and which is the default encoding of a string anytime you `decode()` it.)
    # note that you will return a shorter string, because (again) `ascii` can only represent 
    # 128 characters by default, whereas some of your `utf-8` string is represented by 
    # characters b/w 129 & 255.
```

I hope that helps and makes sense.  There are a lot of materials online discussing this problem (including multiple of my own questions -- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20555142/2058922) :))

Comment: `print chardet.detect(text)['encoding']` shows "UTF-8" because your text string is saved and encoded as UTF-8. I can make this show `windows-1252` if I encode the file differently.

Comment: Rare downvoting from me as your answer is too misleading to other users. Python 2.x is just as capable in terms of Unicode support. Your `glitch()` method contains numerous fallacies, which will prevent users from understanding Unicode support correctly